# Consolidating multiple sites with “duplicate” landing pages. SEO consequences?

Tags: seo, redirects, website-design

A client of mine has four separate domains (very good ones, I might add) that are all almost exact copies of each other, with only "SEO keywords" being different. While making a new site for them that's modern and responsive, I'm also consolidating to a single site to avoid duplicate content.

Should I do a bunch of individual redirects from particular urls to new, relevant ones, or should I just do a blanket redirect to the home page of the new site? For example, should I redirect `olddomain.com/contact.html` to `newdomain.com/contact-us`, or just `newdomain.com`? Does it make an SEO difference?

Secondary question: I also have an idea to have multiple landing pages. The landing pages would have localized keywords aimed at bringing in search results. For instance, I may have a landing page called `domain.com/new-york` and another one called `domain.com/miami`. Is this a good design decision for SEO?

Comment: What you redirect has to be discovered during the process. We cannot tell you what to redirect - old pages to new pages. As for the extra domains, they generally add no value. You can redirect all the extra domains to the one domain using a blanket 301 redirect then inventory important links and pages and redirect these on the new/one domain. Personally, I would consider deleting the extra domains if they do not offer any significant link value. Sometimes it is just best to make a big change for future gain. Just make sure you pay attention to branding and mark-up. Cheers!!

Comment: As for your landing pages, it would all depend upon what content you can create for these pages. If they are generally duplicate, then I would prefer not to create them and do localization on your About or Contact page with mark-up. Only you can make that decision. There is nothing wrong with having these pages if there is enough unique content per location. For example, what services are available, contact information, brands you serve locally, etc.

Comment: As it is, this would require two separate answers (as evident in the comments above). You could edit this to remove the second question and ask that separately, however it's fairly opinion-based as pointed out above. Both have really been asked here multiple times, some of which you'll see listed under the "Related" column on the right, and others are Searchable above. I'd suggest having a look at those first, and if you're still in need of additional information not covered in those, then edit your question(s) above and it will be added to the review queue for consideration to reopen it.